# Pycharm output empty value

Tags: python, pycharm, valueerror

I have the following code:

```
def area(x, y):
    return x*y
w = int(input())
h = int(input())
print(area(w,h))
```

Every time I run it in Pycharm,**VS works fine**, it gave me this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Also I tried switching int() to float() and this error appear:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

It seems like the second input is always empty .
Thanks in advance

Python 3.8
PyCharm 2022.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue seems to be known and fixed:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5609658115218-error-on-user-input
Simply upgrade PyCharm and it will work.